# SimpleRole / SimpleMember - add user to role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

MVC4 using SimpleMembership & Role.

So after 18 hours of research, googling, trial & error, etc I finally have simpleMembership working.  However, after multiple step-throughs and different scenarios, I cant find where the  new user is assigned to a role.  I have roles in my webpages_Roles table.

So, does one of the 4000 built-in methods do the assigning and I just need to add it somewhere? Or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Darin - Actuallu I have found the majority of MVC to be quite straight forward.  I started about a year ago and really enjoy it.  But Simple(yeah, right)Membership and Membership in general has proven to be, borderline incomprehensible.  I was about to just write my own, then it suddenly started working. By Magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a user to a role with the following code:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUsersToRole("user1", "user2", "user3", ... , "yourrolename");
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, I will try that.  Actually I will use AddUserToRole, so when someone signs up, they get assigned a role.